# Leading "0" in Spring Cloud Sleuth's trace ID truncated in some spans

Tags: spring-boot, zipkin, spring-cloud-sleuth

I'm using version 1.1.2.RELEASE of spring-cloud-starter-sleuth alongside Spring Boot 1.4.2.RELEASE and spring-cloud-dependencies CAMDEN-SR3. I found that sometimes when the generated trace ID has a leading 0 (e.g. "096ad8c3ed8d4a20"), some of the subsequent spans would record a trace ID without the leading zero (in this case "96ad8c3ed8d4a20").

Is this a known bug? It's not always reproduceable but I can definitely detect this intermittently. And it's not very consistent either. For e.g., one of my REST API calls generates a total of 6 spans and this issue only occurred for one of the spans.

Comment: Are you sure all applications are using the latest versions of Sleuth? AFAIR this was fixed a long time ago (where by "this" I mean adding zeros to the beginning of the ID)

Comment: Yes, I'm sure that I'm using 1.1.2.RELEASE in all my microservices. I had noted that a previous issue reported on this was fixed as part of https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/issues/449 but still seem to experience it intermittently.

Comment: Have you tried the latest Camden release maybe? Don't know if that will fix anything for that matter but it's worth a try.

Comment: when you describe the generated trace ID having different length, where are you seeing it? are you looking at logs, http headers, or the data returned by zipkin's ui?